# What is the reverse postorder?

Tags: algorithm, static-analysis

This is the explanation in wikipedia: [Data-flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis#The_order_matters)

> This is a typical iteration order for forward data-flow problems. In reverse-postorder iteration, a node is visited before any of its successor nodes has been visited, except when the successor is reached by a back edge. (Note that this is not the same as preorder.)

Can someone explain this in greater detail?

Comment: It feels like you really want to be posting in the CS forum: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried [following the link in the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Vertex_orderings)?

Comment: Did the linked explanation of [Reverse postorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Vertex_orderings) shed any light on it for you?

Comment: This article has a diagram for postorder that's easier to understand: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: @montewhizdoh Sorry, I don't know this forum before. I will next time ∩_∩.

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you so much!

Comment: @JimMischel What's the difference between the Level-order and the  Reverse-postorder ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Reverse postordering as the name suggests produces the exact opposite of postorder traversal.

**Example**

[image]

For the above referred directed graph

postorder traversals are D B C A and D C B A

reverse postorder traversals are A C B D and A B C D

**How to obtain reverse postorder traversal**

One way is to run postorder traversal and push the nodes in a stack in postorder.

Then pop out the nodes to get the reverse postorder.

**Application**

Topological sorting using depth first search.

Comment: What is the different between reverse post-order DFS and BFS?!

Comment: @YasamanGhassemi for trees, they are the same (and also to pre-order DFS). For graphs (well, DAGs), they can be different if there are nodes that are both siblings and parent-child.